# "For" Loop, gradually slowing down

Tags: java, performance, for-loop

I wrote a code that shows the progress of the loop. Part of codes:

```
String instantBinary = "";
for (int i = 0; i < Text.length(); i++) {
    //Sometimes the text is too long                        

    if (Text.length() > 100) {
        if (Text.length() % (Text.length() / 100) == i % (Text.length() / 100)) {
            WTProgress = "Translate Progress.. %" + (i * 100 / Text.length());
            System.out.println(WTProgress); 
        }
    }

    switch("" + Text.charAt(i)) {
        case "1": 
            instantBinary += "0000000";
            break;
        case "2": 
            instantBinary += "0000001";
            break;
        case "3": 
            instantBinary += "0000010";
            break;
        case "4": 
            instantBinary += "0000011";
            break;
        case "5": 
            instantBinary += "0000100";
            break;
        case "6": 
            instantBinary += "0000101";
            break;
        case "7": 
            instantBinary += "0000110";
            break;
        case "8": 
            instantBinary += "0000111";
            break;
        case "9": 
            instantBinary += "0001000";
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Unknown character found \"" + Text.charAt(i) + "\""):
    }
```

In fact, translation codes are not that short. There are 128 characters. But that's not the problem. I recently tried translating 300 pages of text. It reached 25% in 5 minutes. But it took 3 hours to reach 100%. How do I solve this problem?

EDIT:  I solved the problem. The source of the problem is every time I perform a += operation on a string, I actually creating a new string instance, and they are getting longer and longer. As you said, I solved the problem using StringBuilder. Translation codes work at least 1000 times faster. Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: If you want to speed things up then yes...you can use StringBuilder as others have suggested but since the amount of data you want to process is so large you may want to share the workload by using ExecutorService and have several threads take care of business.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating your translation in memory. The longer the loop runs, the more memory you need.

1. Increase memory using -Xmx
2. Use a StringBuilder.
3. Initialize it with the correct size needed for the full text (a quick look at the code tells me it is a constant factor of the original text size.

   ```
   StringBuilder instantBinary = new StringBuilder (text.length()*7);
   ```
4. Switch on chars, not Strings

   ```
   switch(Text.charAt(i)){
       case '1': instantBinary.append("0000000"); break;
   ```
5. Don't do it in memory. Read from one file, write the translation to the output file on the fly.

Comment: I would add, if output is a binary, it is better to use ByteBuffer, and if needed some specific to write there, then make just one additional wrapper method around ByteBuffer to write there.

Comment: Translation codes work at least 1000 times faster. Thank you thousands of times..

Answer (score 8):

Every time you do `instantBinary+="00000000"`, you are re-creating a new string object and copying all the giant amounts of data from the older `String` into it (this is just how java works)
You should create a `StringBuilder` Object and use `myStringBuilder.append ( "00000000" )` and to finally get you string, use `myStringBuilder.toString ()`

More info [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder-java)

Answer (score 3):

`String` (instantBinary) is an immutable type.  Every time you perform a `+=` operation on a string, you are actually creating a new string instance, and they are getting longer and longer.

Try using a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` for instantBinary instead.

Comment: I would not recommend a StringBuffer, as synchronization isn't needed in this case.  A StringBuilder would suffice.